# How do I use pg_dump and pg_restore to move a large database to another machine?

Tags: postgresql, migration

I'm a bit unclear on how to use the `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` duo to move a large-ish database.

Here is the command I use to dump the database (the host and username are taken from environmental variables):

```
pg_dump --dbname=mydb --format=custom > mydb.dump
```

I use the `custom` format because I do this over the network and want to use compression.

When I now try to restore it, I tried this:

```
pg_restore --dbname=mydb --no-owner mydb.dump
```

But I get:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydb" failed: FATAL:  database "mydb" does not exist
```

I tried next with the `--create` option, but that yields the same error message.

Finally I tried passing `template1` as a `--dbname` option:

```
pg_restore --dbname=template1 --no-owner --create mydb.dump
```

But here is what I get:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2125; 1262 16395 DATABASE mydb mydbuser
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_US.utf8"
    Command was: CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf8';



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not reconnect to database: FATAL:  database "mydb" does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

When you do

```
pg_restore --dbname=mydb --no-owner mydb.dump
```

You are trying to connect to the `mydb` database which still does not exist. Connect to an existent one and use the `--create` parameter:

```
pg_restore --dbname=existentdb --no-owner --create mydb.dump
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: I believe this is what I do, when I connect to the `template1` database, is it not? Yet I get this error message mentioned in my question.

Comment: @lindelof That happens because the `mydb` database could not be created while connected to `template1`. Fix the `invalid locale name` problem first.